# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in swift take time to load

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a problem with my `UITableView`. When the `UIViewController` ended to load   the `UITableViewCell` take about 4 at 6 sec to load the first time. When i call again my `UIViewController`, it's load properly. Did i miss something ?

any help will be appreciated :)

**The load UIViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.backgroundColor  = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.webview.backgroundColor    = PPP.COLOR.BackgroundDarkBrown
    self.webview.contentMode        = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.webview.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true        
    self.webview.alpha = 0
    self.tableView.alpha = 1

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SummaryProduct", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SummaryOrder", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
}
```

**My Declaration of the TableView**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // FOR ORDER
    if section == 1 { return 1 }
    // FOR PRODUCT LIST
    let count = self.cart.getTotalProducts()
    if count > 0 { return count }
    return count
}

func tableViewForCellProduct(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SummaryProductTableViewCell
    cell.configureCellWithIndexPath(self, indexPath: indexPath, cart: self.cart)
    return cell
}

func tableViewForCellOrder(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SummaryOrderTableViewCell
    cell.configureCellWithIndexPath(self, indexPath: indexPath, cart: self.cart)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        return self.tableViewForCellProduct(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    default:
        return self.tableViewForCellOrder(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it taking 4 seconds? Probably loading the cell Nibs first time. Second time they are probably cached in ram somewhere.

Comment: it's taking time in `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SummaryProductTableViewCell` and `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SummaryOrderTableViewCell`

Comment: if there is a cache, can i boost it ?

Comment: I doubt it. You could create two cells in your app delegate on app load which would most likely populate any cache up front meaning your first usage would be as fast as the second. However, first are you sure these cells do not cause a database load or something else on first usage to happen which you have added yourself?

Comment: very weird  solution but it works thanks @RoryMcKinnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is probably loading the cells for the first time. Second time they are probably cached in ram somewhere.

You could move the delay to load time by creating two cells in your app delegate on app load which would most likely populate any cache up front meaning your first usage would be as fast as the second.

Comment: I created cells in my appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions mathod as follows: var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "user_cell"). This did not solve my issue.

Comment: @KhaledAlanezi You would be best to create a new question as your issue is probably not the same. If performance on loading a controller is is your issue you need to determine where the time is going. For this question, it was using time in the cell creation. Sounds like your issue resides elsewhere?

Comment: My application freezes when loading a UITableView for a couple of seconds and this only happens the first time of launching the UIViewController that contains the table view. The freezing happen exactly the very first time the tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is called. Hence, I assumed it is the same problem.